# Health check times out for managed instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, health-check

## Problem

I have a health check for a managed instance group on GCP that continuously times out. Therefore, the group manager thinks all instances are always unhealthy.

[image]

My guess is I've misconfigured the firewall, but I can't determine if that's the case or how I've misconfigured it.

> Note: I'm not asking about the load balance health checks. I'm asking about the managed instance group health checks for auth-healing.

### Error

In the "Errors" tab of the managed instance group, I always see the following error:

```
WAITING_FOR_HEALTHY_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

Waiting for HEALTHY state timed out (autohealingPolicy.initialDelay=300 sec) for instance projects/project-402019/zones/us-central1-f/instances/server-20bd and health check projects/project-402019/global/healthChecks/server-health-check.
```

### Debug steps

- When I ssh into a VM and run `curl http://127.0.0.1:3001/hello`, I successfully get `http://127.0.0.1:3001/hello` (I'm running a simple echo service right now).
- I've set up the firewall to allow incomming traffic on port 3001 as described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs#setting_up_an_autohealing_policy). See firewall setup below.
- Set the initialization period and autohealing initial delay to 5+ minutes in case it takes forever to start up (I can ssh into the VM after 30s and curl successfully).
- Set the health check timeout to 30 seconds (when I curl it responds instantly).
- Opened all ports on the firewall.

## Setup

### Firewall

[image]

### Health check

I've also tried multiple different settings here:

- TCP vs. HTTP
- Intervals/timeouts ranging from 2-30 seconds.
- Healthy/unhealthy thresholds from 1-3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out your binary needs to listen on `0.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1`.

Once I made that change to my code, everything else worked.